# getBoundingClientRect() returns same values for all children if first child has any negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, getboundingclientrect

**The Context**

I'm building an infinite horizontal scroll of images:

```
<div class="infinite-thumbs">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="thumb thumb-one">
    <img src="2.jpg" class="thumb thumb-two">
    <img src="3.jpg" class="thumb thumb-three">
    ...
    <img src="10.jpg" class="thumb thumb-ten">
</div>

<style lang="stylus">

    .infinite-thumbs
        position absolute
        width 100%
        height 180px
        bottom 40px
        white-space nowrap
        overflow auto
        overflow-y hidden

    .thumb
        position relative
        display inline-block
        width 200px
        height 180px

</style>
```

Learn more about Stylus here: [stylus-lang.com](http://stylus-lang.com)

And then I've got some `jQuery/JS` to handle the cloning and appending of images when they're off-screen:

```
function scrollUpdate() {

    $('.thumb').each(function() {

        var bounding = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        if (bounding.right < 0) {
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.clone(true).appendTo('.infinite-thumbs');
            $el.remove();
        }

    });

}

$('.infinite-thumbs').on('scroll', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
});
```

So `scrollUpdate()` loops over each of the `.thumb` elements and checks to see if it's visible on-screen. If it's not (`bounding.right < 0`) then it gets cloned and appended to the end of the `.infinite-thumbs` element.

**The Problem**

The problem I have is that once one of the `.thumb` elements returns a negative value for `bounding.right` *all* the `.thumb` elements return the exact same set of `bounding` values.

So when all are visible, I get this in my console:

```
.thumb-one: { top : 0, right : 200, ... }
.thumb-two: { top : 0, right : 400, ... }
.thumb-three: { top : 0, right : 600, ... }
...
.thumb-ten: { top : 0, right : 2000, ... }
```

But as soon as the first child element (`.thumb-one`) obtains a negative `bounding.right` value, I get this in my console:

```
.thumb-one: { top : 0, right : -1, ... }
.thumb-two: { top : 0, right : -1, ... }
.thumb-three: { top : 0, right : -1, ... }
...
.thumb-ten: { top : 0, right : -1, ... }
```

What gives? Why would they all return a `bounding` object with the exact same values just because one of them is off-screen?

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

**NOTE:**

> Both `$.fn.offset()` and `$.fn.position()` behave in the same way as
>   `getBoundingClientRect()`; they return the same set of values for each
>   `.thumb` once `.thumb-one` has a negative value in its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you remove the element before check all the thumbs' positions. Removing the first element causes that the next element becomes the first, going off-screen. This way, every thumb will assume the same 'right' position.

**The solution**
Create a temporary array outside the 'each' cycle and use it to save the off-screen thumbs. Then, after the cycle, clone, remove and append elements in the same way as before. Something like this:

```
function scrollUpdate() {
    var offScreenElements = [];
    $('.thumb').each(function() {

        var bounding = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        if (bounding.right < 0) {
            offScreenElements.push($(this));
        }
    });
    $.each(offScreenElements, function(index, element) {
        element.clone(true).appendTo('.infinite-thumbs');
        element.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: A quick test by disabling the `$.fn.clone()` and `$.fn.remove()` shows that you're on to something! I'll chase this down ...

Comment: I've added some code (not tested, but i think you'll can use it to reach your goal)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Alberto, saved me from going out of my mind there ;)